# cURL not loaded under Win10 / Apache 2.4 / PHP 7.0.10 x64

Tags: windows, curl, php-7

I installed Apache 2.4 x64 and PHP 7.0.10 x64 on my Win10 computer. Everything is working fine, but cURL is not loaded. I can see this error message in my Application Windows log:

**The description for Event ID 4 from source PHP-7.0.10 cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.**

......

**php[10952]
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\PHP7\ext\php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.**

The DLL file is in my extensions directory and all other extensions are loaded with no problems. I found some advises, that ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll have to be copied to from PHP directory to Apache BIN directory or to Windows/System32 directory - non of them works for me. Any idea, what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I changed PHPRC and PATH system variables from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7 directory ( I am running 2 Apache instances with both PHP versions ) and it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same error with apache. When starting PHP from command line it works perfect.

UPDATE: I've just fixed it by upgrading apache from 2.4.18 to 2.4.23

Comment: Unfortunately, my Apache is 2.4.23

Comment: I just tried to move to 32bit version and the issue is there as well.